# Best way to query multiple 'categories' mysql php?

Tags: php, mysql

I am probably overlooking something simple--

Some of the news items has 2 categories checked, and other times it has all 4 check. 
I know I can do OR '' OR '' OR '' OR '' -- but I think there is a better way.

The question: How could I query this to output: if the story has category 10,13 or 10,13,15 or 10,13,15,16 or 10,15 or 10,13?? ('10' is the parent category) -- without doing a query like that??

```
WHERE news.id = story.post_id AND news.category LIKE '10,13,15,16'
```

Comment: Your schema perplexes me a bit. Perhaps category be its own table (`categories`) and then you can use a `categories_news` cross-reference table. Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say:

```
AND new.category IN ('10,13', '10,13,15', '10,13,15,16', '10,15', '10,13')
```

Which is slightly cleaner that using many `OR`'s.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize you can query "IN" ha.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE news.id = story.post_id AND news.category in (10, 13, 15, 16)
```